# java varargs methods behave differently

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Given the code below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CC().ff(1);
    }
}

class CC {
    public static void ff(int cc) {
        System.out.println("bbbbb");
    }

    public static void ff(int... ints) {
        System.out.println("aaaaaaa");
    }
}
```

output will be:

```
aaaaaaa

bbbbb
```

If I change the third line to `CC.ff(1)`, output will be:

```
bbbbb
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: your third line *is* `new CC().FF(1);`. Please post your original code , otherwise it is difficult to understand your question. BTW you code cannot be compiled: your method is called `ff()` but you try to invoke `FF()`

Comment: I edited your code to call `ff` instead of `FF`, so that it would at least compile.  I suggest you try again to build a simple repro case of what you're trying to explain, because this - even if it compiles - probably isn't it.

Comment: Seems like something is missing from the sample code.

Comment: @AlexR: actually, he's suggesting changing to the static `CC.ff(1)`.  (Not that it matters.)

Comment: hmmm, how do you generate your first output?

Comment: As it stands, copying and pasting your code and running it only produces bbbbb

Comment: @Edward Thomson, you are right. The brain works hard at 1 AM. :)

Comment: @AlexR: I puzzled over that one for a while myself.  I'm convinced that if I stare at this problem long enough, I'll finally understand what the OP is actually trying to convey.  I do not think I'll be successful.

Comment: I have just tried it. It prints `bbbbb` twice. Something is wrong in your experiment. Please try again and be careful with `static` word. I believe that you just forgot to make on of your `ff`s static in one of your experiments.

Comment: This is probably a rule buried somewhere in the JLS, stating that when resolving methods calls, the compiler will consider non-varargs methods before varargs ones. (Instead of complaining about ambiguous overloads which would probably be more useful.)

Answer (score 2):

If I read what I think is the [relevant section of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.1) right (it's not exactly light bedtime reading), looking for what method call invokes which method occurs in three phases that search through the following sets of methods in this order:

1. [Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Subtyping](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.2)
2. [Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Method Invocation Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.3)
3. [Applicable Variable Arity Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.4)

In each of those sections, it is mentioned that if applicable methods are found in a given phase, the method to be called is chosen from those. Only if the phase yields no applicable methods does the search proceed to the next phase.

Since variable-arity methods are searched last, this means that any matching method that isn't variable-arity will be called in preference to those.